# How to host web api in memory?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have web api controller and i want to perform an integration tests. So I followed the article [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/) to configured the in-memory Web API host.
My integration test and web api are two different projects in same VS solution.

Below is the code

**Web API Controller**

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{

    public DocumentController(IDomainService domainService)
    {
        _domainService = domainService;            
    }        

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Update([FromBody]IEnumerable<Document> request)
    {
        return await _domainService.Update(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

**Integration Test**

```
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTests
    {
        private HttpServer _server;
        private string _url = "http://www.strathweb.com/";

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Default", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
            config.MessageHandlers.Add()
            _server = new HttpServer(config);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void UpdateTransformedDocuments()
        {
            var doc = new Document()
            {
              // set all properties
            }
            var client = new HttpClient(_server);
            var request = createRequest<Document>("api/document/Update", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post, doc, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            using (var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
            {
                 // do something with response here
            }
        }        

        private HttpRequestMessage createRequest<T>(string url, string mthv, HttpMethod method, T content, MediaTypeFormatter formatter) where T : class
        {
            Create HttpRequestMessage here
        }
    }
```

However im getting error

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

How & where do I tell the HttpServer to execute DocumentController?

**Update1**
So I fixed above error by changing the `[TestIntialize]` code as below

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        UnityWebApiActivator.Start();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        _server = new HttpServer(config);
    }
```

I don't get 404 error now. However Unity is not able to resolve `DocumentController`. The HttpResponse contains error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'DocumentController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

In `TestInitialize` method I'm calling `UnityWebApiActivator.Start()` which registers all the require types  with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

i resolved my 2nd issue by setting 'HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver'

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //UnityWebApiActivator.Start();
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        _server = new HttpServer(config);
    }
```